# Problem combo box does not connect to database

Tags: c#, database, t-sql, combobox, windows-forms-designer

I have a problem with merging data in combo box on the following code. I presented my solution, but it shows me an error "Unable to bind to new display member. Arg_ParamName_Name" at: CB.Trucker.ValueMember

```
            
            SqlConnection co = new SqlConnection("Data Source=\"localhost, 1433\";Initial Catalog=Transporting;User ID=******;Password=*******");
            co.Open();
            SqlCommand comd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CONCAT(EmpFirstName,' ',EmpLastName) as Trucker FROM Employees ", co);
            
            SqlDataReader readerv3;
            readerv3 = comd.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable data = new DataTable();

            data.Columns.Add("Trucker", typeof(string));
            data.Load(readerv3);
            CbTrucker.ValueMember = "Trucker";
            CbTrucker.DataSource = data;
            co.Close();
```

`CbTruck{}` field has defined values

```
 public string Ordtruck { get => CbTruck.Text; set => CbTruck.Text=value; }
```

I have no idea what's wrong. I'm using the same script to display a different problem I even wrote a procedure, that only displays these values, but it still doesn't work.Even when the select (comd) query is modified by data.Columns.Add, it still displays the same error

Comment: Please show enough code for us to understand the question. Is `CbTrucker` a property or a class? If it's a property, please share the property declaration and the definition of its type, if it's a class, please share the class definition.

Comment: Just a SWAG, but since your `select` query (`comd`) isn't going to modified by `data.Columns.Add`, there probably isn't any data to be had. Especially after `comd.ExecuteReader()` has completed running the query. Are you authorized to disclose the error message?

Comment: @sbridewell CbTrucker is the name of a Combobox and in it I don't define or set anything but refer to it

Comment: @HABO yes as much as possible this is the error : "Unable to bind to new display member. Arg_ParamName_Name"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was a problem with calling the CBTruck class, which was called in an earlier event and conflicted with the current example, it was enough to remove the previously used class